# Advice on best data structure to use in Redis?

Tags: json, redis

I'm new to redis, and would like to start storing an object that's currently JSON in redis instead. But I need some advice on the best data structure to use.

Basically, the object stores information about which user has looked at which page. Here's the JSON:

```
all_pageviews = {
    'unique_user_session_id_1' : { 'page' : 2, 'country' : 'DE' },
    'unique_user_session_id_2': { 'page' : 2, 'country' : 'FR' } 
     ...
};
```

I've been using a JSON object with the user IDs as keys because that way I can ensure the keys are unique, which is important for various reasons in my app.

I'm going to want to query it efficiently in the following ways:

- By user: get all data related to `unique_user_session_id_2`.
- By page: get all user objects related to page number `2`.

Any thoughts on what would be the best redis structure to use? Ordering doesn't matter for the purposes of my app, but querying efficiently does.

Please let me know if I have explained myself badly, or if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To look up data in redis by multiple keys, you'll have to use multiple structures.

I would use a [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) to map user_session_ids to the json string, and a [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) to map pages to user_session_ids

Comment: So use two different 'tables', with the attendant danger of the information ending up out of sync? There isn't a way to search by value in Redis?

Comment: Sadly, no. You might consider MongoDB if this is just one of many JSON objects you'd like to persist.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need multiple objects, just a sensible way to query the same object by either of two values. I could rewrite it as `{ user_id: 12345, page_id: 2, country: 'DE' }` if that would help, just as long as I can query by the value of both `user_id` and `page_id` - is that really not possible in Redis?!

Comment: It is possible in Redis, just like he explained. You need to maintain your own indexes if you want to query by something other than the data's key. This is actually extremely powerful as you can choose the best possible structure for your indexes based on your application's use case. The issue, obviously, is the added complexity and the fact that your application is responsible for maintaining index consistency. This is not unusual in NoSQL land but seems odd to people used to RDBMS's.